# OpenShift gitconfig Permission denied

Tags: git, jenkins, openshift, redhat

I currently have a Jenkins server running on OpenShift, but as soon as a build requires git, I get the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file /var/lib/openshift/<id>/.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

After connecting to the gear server and checking the owner of the .gitconfig file, I discovered that I do not own that file.

(ls -la output)

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 107 Jun 12 12:21 ./.gitconfig
```

I tried to remove the file and let git recreate it, but as soon as I run the rm command, I get the following output.

```
ERROR: Refusing unsafe deletion: ./.gitconfig
```

How should I proceed here?

Comment: Likely https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=977034

Comment: Doesn't seem like it since I'm not trying to change/delete the actual app, I just want to delete/reset the gitconfig file so Jenkins can use it to build git-based projects.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to do chown jenkinsUser .gitconfig

You'd need to be root to do that su root (or if sudo is available). Also, if your jenkins installation is vanilla, the user is called jenkins.

Comment: Sadly on RedHat OpenShift we don't get root access, nor sudo, making chown impossible to be executed on a file owned by root.

Comment: Was .git/* existing before as root? If so, your best bet is to create a new directory as jenkins user and point jenkins (in manage jenkins) to the new directory.

However, this .git directory should have came from somewhere, if  you can tell how, you might be able to change the ownership of the files

Answer (score 0):

which account you have used to remove the file?

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 107 Jun 12 12:21 ./.gitconfig
```

this line told you that the owner of .gitconfig file can read and write,while the group owner belong to and other users only have read permission.so only owner and root account can do rm action

Comment: I used my RedHat OpenShift account (The only one I have access to).